# android my gridview data is not showing all items which is coming from server?

Tags: android

```
public class ExploreScreenActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener, OnItemClickListener,IServerResponse{
private ImageButton _refreshBtn=null;
private ImageButton _searchBtn=null;
private Button _cancelBtn=null;
private EditText _searchText=null;
public TextWatcher filterTextWatcher;

private TextView _exploreTxt=null;
private LinearLayout _search_all_layout=null;
private ImageButton _allSearchBtn=null;
private ImageButton _brandsSearchBtn=null;
private ImageButton _itemsSearchBtn=null;
private ImageButton _peopleSearchBtn=null;
private SharedPreferences _sPrefs=null;
public ArrayList<Object> _itemList=null;
private ArrayList<Object>_brandlist=null;
private ArrayList<Object>_alluserlist=null;
private ArrayList<Object>_peoplelist=null;
private ArrayList<Object>_defaultlist=null;

private String type=null;;
private String searchString=null;;
private GridView _explorGridView=null;

private GridSearchNewAdapter adapter=null;
private GridBrandadapter brandadapter=null;
private GridAllUserAdapter alladapter=null;
private GridItemAdapter itemadapter=null;
private GridUserAdapter useradapter=null;
private Defaultadapter adapter11=null;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_explorscreen);

    _sPrefs=getSharedPreferences("myPrefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    _itemList = new ArrayList<Object>();
    _brandlist=new ArrayList<Object>();
    _alluserlist=new ArrayList<Object>();
    _peoplelist=new ArrayList<Object>();
    _defaultlist=new ArrayList<Object>();
    _refreshBtn=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.refresh_btn);
    _refreshBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
    _search_all_layout=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.search_all_layout);
    _searchBtn=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.search_btn);
    _searchBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
    _searchText=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.search_edtTxt);
    _searchText.setOnClickListener(this);
    _cancelBtn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.cancel_btn);
    _cancelBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
    _explorGridView=(GridView)findViewById(R.id.explor_gridView);
    _exploreTxt=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.explor_textView);
    _allSearchBtn=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.all_search_btn);
    _allSearchBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
    _brandsSearchBtn=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.brands_search_btn);
    _brandsSearchBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
    _itemsSearchBtn=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.items_search_btn);
    _itemsSearchBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
    _peopleSearchBtn=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.people_search_btn);
    _peopleSearchBtn.setOnClickListener(this);

    type= _searchText.getText().toString();
    searchString=_searchText.getText().toString();
    getSearch(type,searchString);

    _explorGridView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    _searchText.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
            if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEARCH) {
                Intent intent=new Intent(ExploreScreenActivity.this, FeedSelectedActivity.class);
                TabGroupActivity parentActivity = (TabGroupActivity)getParent();
                parentActivity.startChildActivity("feedselected", intent);

                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
    onResume();
    {
        super.onResume();
        getSearch(type, searchString);
    }
    _searchText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            searchString     = _searchText.getText().toString().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());
            searchString    =s.toString();

            getSearch(type,searchString);
            alladapter.filter(searchString);

        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1,
                int arg2, int arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                int arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
    });
}



@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    TabGroupActivity parentActivity=(TabGroupActivity)getParent();
    Intent intent=null;
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.refresh_btn:
        break;
    case R.id.search_btn:

        _searchText.setText("");
        intent=new Intent(this, FeedSelectedActivity.class);
        parentActivity.startChildActivity("feedselect", intent);
        break;
    case R.id.cancel_btn:
        _exploreTxt.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        _searchBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        _search_all_layout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        _cancelBtn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        _searchText.setText("");
        //  _explorGridView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        break;
    case R.id.search_edtTxt:
        _exploreTxt.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        _searchBtn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        _cancelBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        _search_all_layout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        break;
    case R.id.all_search_btn:
        _brandsSearchBtn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.brand_deselected);
        _itemsSearchBtn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.items_deselected);
        _peopleSearchBtn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.people_deselected);
        _allSearchBtn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.all_selected);

        type="all";
        getSearch( type, searchString);

        break;
    case R.id.brands_search_btn:
        _brandsSearchBtn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.brand_selected);
        _itemsSearchBtn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.items_deselected);
        _peopleSearchBtn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.people_deselected);
        _allSearchBtn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.all_deselected);
        type="brand";
        getSearch(type,searchString);

        break;
    case R.id.items_search_btn:
        _brandsSearchBtn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.brand_deselected);
        _itemsSearchBtn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.items_selected);
        _peopleSearchBtn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.people_deselected);
        _allSearchBtn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.all_deselected);
        type="item";
        getSearch(type,searchString);

        break;
    case R.id.people_search_btn:
        _brandsSearchBtn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.brand_deselected);
        _itemsSearchBtn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.items_deselected);
        _peopleSearchBtn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.people_selected);
        _allSearchBtn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.all_deselected);
        type="user";
        getSearch(type,searchString);

        break;
    default:
        break;
    }       
}
private void getSearch(String type,String searchString) {
    if (NetworkAvailablity.checkNetworkStatus(ExploreScreenActivity.this)) {
        ArrayList<NameValuePair> requestParaList = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        requestParaList.add(new BasicNameValuePair("type", _sPrefs.getString("type",type)));

        requestParaList.add(new BasicNameValuePair("searchstring", _sPrefs.getString("searchstring",searchString)));



        //  requestParaList.add(new BasicNameValuePair("type", type));
        //  requestParaList.add(new BasicNameValuePair("searchstring",searchString));

        WebServiceCommunicator.getInstance().registerForServerResponse((IServerResponse) ExploreScreenActivity.this);
        WebServiceCommunicator.getInstance().callGetAppWebService(false,
                this,
                WSConstant.getUrl(WSConstant.METHOD_SEARCH),
                ExploreScreenActivity.this, WSConstant.PID_SEARCH, false,
                requestParaList);
    }
}

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long arg3) {
    Intent intent=new Intent(this, FeedSelectedActivity.class);
    TabGroupActivity parentActivity = (TabGroupActivity)getParent();
    parentActivity.startChildActivity("feedselected", intent);
    //startActivity(intent);
}

private Handler _handler = new Handler() {
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        switch (msg.arg2) {
        case WSConstant.PID_SEARCH:
            getJsonResponse(msg.obj.toString(), msg.arg2);
            break;

        default:
            break;
        }
    }
};
private void getJsonResponse(String response, int arg2) {
    JSONObject jObject=null;
    try {
        jObject = new JSONObject(response);
        JSONArray list = jObject.getJSONArray("posts");

        for (int i = 0; i < list.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject element = list.getJSONObject(i);
            if ( type.equalsIgnoreCase("all")) {
                AllBean bean= new AllBean();
                bean.setid(element.getString("id"));
                bean.setfullname(element.getString("fullname"));
                bean.setusername(element.getString("username"));
                bean.setprofile_photo(element.getString("profile_photo"));
                bean.setprofile_type(element.getString("profile_type"));
                bean.setprofile(element.getString("profile"));
                //  _alluserlist.clear();
                _alluserlist.add(bean);




            }
            if (_alluserlist.size()!=0) {

                alladapter=new GridAllUserAdapter(ExploreScreenActivity.this, _alluserlist);
                _explorGridView.setAdapter(alladapter);
            }

            else if (type.equalsIgnoreCase("brand")) {
                BrandBean bean= new BrandBean();
                bean.setbrand_id(element.getString("brand_id"));
                bean.setbrand_name(element.getString("brand_name"));
                bean.setbrand_photo(element.getString("brand_photo"));

                _brandlist.add(bean);
            }
            if (_brandlist.size()!=0) {

                brandadapter=new GridBrandadapter(ExploreScreenActivity.this, _brandlist);
                _explorGridView.setAdapter(brandadapter);
            }

            else if ( type.equalsIgnoreCase("item")) {

                ItemBean bean= new ItemBean();
                bean.setitem_id(element.getString("item_id"));
                bean.setitem_name(element.getString("item_name"));
                bean.setitem_photo(element.getString("item_photo"));

                _itemList.add(bean);
            }
            if (_itemList.size()!=0) {
                itemadapter=new GridItemAdapter(ExploreScreenActivity.this, _itemList);
                _explorGridView.setAdapter(itemadapter);
            }
            else if (type.equalsIgnoreCase("user")) {

                UserBean bean= new UserBean();
                bean.setid(element.getString("id"));
                bean.setfullname(element.getString("fullname"));
                bean.setusername(element.getString("username"));
                bean.setprofile_photo(element.getString("profile_photo"));

                _peoplelist.add(bean);
            }
            if (_peoplelist.size()!=0) {

                useradapter=new GridUserAdapter(ExploreScreenActivity.this, _peoplelist);
                _explorGridView.setAdapter(useradapter);
            }
            else {
                DefaultBean bean=new DefaultBean();
                bean.setmedia_id(element.getString("media_id"));
                bean.setthumbnail_image(element.getString("thumbnail_image"));
                bean.setmedia_owner(element.getString("media_owner"));
                _defaultlist.add(bean);
            }
            if (_defaultlist.size()!=0) {

                adapter11=new Defaultadapter(ExploreScreenActivity.this, _defaultlist);
                adapter11.notifyDataSetChanged();
                _explorGridView.setAdapter(adapter11);


            }
        }

    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
    }
}

@Override
public void serverResponse(String response, int processid) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Message msg = new Message();
    msg.obj = response;
    msg.arg2 = processid;
    _handler.sendMessage(msg);  
}


    }
```

i am using gridview for showing my items .the images are coming from server.,i have called one webservice when my activity come on my this activity.,at that time all values are showing.
2in my gridview i have 4 buttons ,when i clik on any button my another webservice calls,now the problem is my new griditems are not showing properly.,they are coming just 2 or 3.,what i do please help me..,i am searching from 2 days on this..,thankyou.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 public class ExploreScreenActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener,   OnItemClickListener,IServerResponse{
private ImageButton _refreshBtn=null;
private ImageButton _searchBtn=null;
private Button _cancelBtn=null;
private EditText _searchText=null;
public TextWatcher filterTextWatcher;

private TextView _exploreTxt=null;
private LinearLayout _search_all_layout=null;
private ImageButton _allSearchBtn=null;
private ImageButton _brandsSearchBtn=null;
private ImageButton _itemsSearchBtn=null;
private ImageButton _peopleSearchBtn=null;
private SharedPreferences _sPrefs=null;

private ArrayList<Object>_alluserlist=null;
private String type=null;;
private String searchString=null;;
private GridView _explorGridView=null;

private GridSearchNewAdapter adapter=null;
private GridAllUserAdapter alladapter=null;
private Defaultadapter adapter11=null;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_explorscreen);

    _sPrefs=getSharedPreferences("myPrefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    _alluserlist=new ArrayList<Object>();
    _refreshBtn=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.refresh_btn);
    _refreshBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
    _search_all_layout=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.search_all_layout);
    _searchBtn=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.search_btn);
    _searchBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
    _searchText=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.search_edtTxt);
    _searchText.setOnClickListener(this);
    _cancelBtn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.cancel_btn);
    _cancelBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
    _explorGridView=(GridView)findViewById(R.id.explor_gridView);
    _exploreTxt=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.explor_textView);
    _allSearchBtn=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.all_search_btn);
    _allSearchBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
    _brandsSearchBtn=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.brands_search_btn);
    _brandsSearchBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
    _itemsSearchBtn=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.items_search_btn);
    _itemsSearchBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
    _peopleSearchBtn=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.people_search_btn);
    _peopleSearchBtn.setOnClickListener(this);

    type= _searchText.getText().toString();
    searchString=_searchText.getText().toString();
    getSearch(type,searchString);

    _explorGridView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    _searchText.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
            if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEARCH) {
                Intent intent=new Intent(ExploreScreenActivity.this, FeedSelectedActivity.class);
                TabGroupActivity parentActivity = (TabGroupActivity)getParent();
                parentActivity.startChildActivity("feedselected", intent);

                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
    onResume();
    {
        super.onResume();
        type="all";
        getSearch(type, searchString);
    }
    _searchText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            searchString     = _searchText.getText().toString().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());
            searchString    =s.toString();
            getSearch(type,searchString);
            alladapter.filter(searchString);

        }
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1,
                int arg2, int arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                int arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
    });
}
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    TabGroupActivity parentActivity=(TabGroupActivity)getParent();
    Intent intent=null;
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.refresh_btn:
        break;
    case R.id.search_btn:

        _searchText.setText("");
        intent=new Intent(this, FeedSelectedActivity.class);
        parentActivity.startChildActivity("feedselect", intent);
        break;
    case R.id.cancel_btn:
        _exploreTxt.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        _searchBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        _search_all_layout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        _cancelBtn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        _searchText.setText("");
        break;
    case R.id.search_edtTxt:
        _exploreTxt.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        _searchBtn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        _cancelBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        _search_all_layout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        break;
    case R.id.all_search_btn:
        _brandsSearchBtn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.brand_deselected);
        _itemsSearchBtn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.items_deselected);
        _peopleSearchBtn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.people_deselected);
        _allSearchBtn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.all_selected);

        type="all";
        getSearch( type, searchString);

        break;
    case R.id.brands_search_btn:
        _brandsSearchBtn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.brand_selected);
        _itemsSearchBtn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.items_deselected);
        _peopleSearchBtn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.people_deselected);
        _allSearchBtn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.all_deselected);
        type="brand";
        getSearch(type,searchString);

        break;
    case R.id.items_search_btn:
        _brandsSearchBtn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.brand_deselected);
        _itemsSearchBtn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.items_selected);
        _peopleSearchBtn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.people_deselected);
        _allSearchBtn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.all_deselected);
        type="item";
        getSearch(type,searchString);

        break;
    case R.id.people_search_btn:
        _brandsSearchBtn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.brand_deselected);
        _itemsSearchBtn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.items_deselected);
        _peopleSearchBtn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.people_selected);
        _allSearchBtn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.all_deselected);
        type="user";
        getSearch(type,searchString);

        break;
    default:
        break;
    }       
}
private void getSearch(String type,String searchString) {
    if (NetworkAvailablity.checkNetworkStatus(ExploreScreenActivity.this)) {
        ArrayList<NameValuePair> requestParaList = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        requestParaList.add(new BasicNameValuePair("type", _sPrefs.getString("type",type)));

        requestParaList.add(new BasicNameValuePair("searchstring", _sPrefs.getString("searchstring",searchString)));
        WebServiceCommunicator.getInstance().registerForServerResponse((IServerResponse) ExploreScreenActivity.this);
        WebServiceCommunicator.getInstance().callGetAppWebService(false,
                this,
                WSConstant.getUrl(WSConstant.METHOD_SEARCH),
                ExploreScreenActivity.this, WSConstant.PID_SEARCH, false,
                requestParaList);
    }
}

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long arg3) {
    Intent intent=new Intent(this, FeedSelectedActivity.class);
    TabGroupActivity parentActivity = (TabGroupActivity)getParent();
    parentActivity.startChildActivity("feedselected", intent);
}

private Handler _handler = new Handler() {
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        switch (msg.arg2) {
        case WSConstant.PID_SEARCH:
            getJsonResponse(msg.obj.toString(), msg.arg2);
            break;

        default:
            break;
        }
    }
};
private void getJsonResponse(String response, int arg2) {
    JSONObject jObject=null;
    try {
        jObject = new JSONObject(response);
        JSONArray list = jObject.getJSONArray("posts");
        _alluserlist.clear();
        for (int i = 0; i < list.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject element = list.getJSONObject(i);
            if ( type.equalsIgnoreCase("all")) {
                AllBean bean= new AllBean();
                bean.setid(element.getString("id"));
                bean.setfullname(element.getString("fullname"));
                bean.setusername(element.getString("username"));
                bean.setprofile_photo(element.getString("profile_photo"));
                bean.setprofile_type(element.getString("profile_type"));
                bean.setprofile(element.getString("profile"));
                _alluserlist.add(bean);
            }


            else if (type.equalsIgnoreCase("brand")) {
                AllBean bean= new AllBean();
                bean.setid(element.getString("brand_id"));
                bean.setusername(element.getString("brand_name"));
                bean.setprofile_photo(element.getString("brand_photo"));

                _alluserlist.add(bean);
            }


            else if ( type.equalsIgnoreCase("item")) {

                AllBean bean= new AllBean();
                bean.setid(element.getString("item_id"));
                bean.setusername(element.getString("item_name"));
                bean.setprofile_photo(element.getString("item_photo"));

                _alluserlist.add(bean);
            }

            else if (type.equalsIgnoreCase("user")) {

                AllBean bean= new AllBean();
                bean.setid(element.getString("id"));
                bean.setfullname(element.getString("fullname"));
                bean.setusername(element.getString("username"));
                bean.setprofile_photo(element.getString("profile_photo"));

                _alluserlist.add(bean);
            }

            else {
                AllBean bean= new AllBean();
                bean.setid(element.getString("id"));
                bean.setfullname(element.getString("fullname"));
                bean.setusername(element.getString("username"));
                bean.setprofile_photo(element.getString("profile_photo"));
                bean.setprofile_type(element.getString("profile_type"));
                bean.setprofile(element.getString("profile"));
                _alluserlist.add(bean);
            }
            if (_alluserlist.size()!=0) {

                alladapter=new GridAllUserAdapter(ExploreScreenActivity.this, _alluserlist);
                _explorGridView.setAdapter(alladapter);
            }
        }
        if (_alluserlist.size()!=0) {

            alladapter=new GridAllUserAdapter(ExploreScreenActivity.this, _alluserlist);
            _explorGridView.setAdapter(alladapter);
        }
        if (_alluserlist.size()!=0) {

            alladapter=new GridAllUserAdapter(ExploreScreenActivity.this, _alluserlist);
            _explorGridView.setAdapter(alladapter);
        }
        if (_alluserlist.size()!=0) {
            alladapter=new GridAllUserAdapter(ExploreScreenActivity.this, _alluserlist);
            _explorGridView.setAdapter(alladapter);
        }
        if (_alluserlist.size()!=0) {

            alladapter=new GridAllUserAdapter(ExploreScreenActivity.this, _alluserlist);
            _explorGridView.setAdapter(alladapter);
        }
    }

    catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
    }

}
@Override
public void serverResponse(String response, int processid) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Message msg = new Message();
    msg.obj = response;
    msg.arg2 = processid;
    _handler.sendMessage(msg);  
 }


  }
```

i got my solution.,here ,i had to add listitem condition below the for loop.its working.here it is.